# CollectionViewSource.View not refreshing at end points

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm running into a problem with my CollectionViewSource.

I'm stopping the user to go BEYOND the the items within the CollectionViewSource to prevent my code from falling over.

I have this:

```
    private CollectionViewSource _source = new CollectionViewSource();
    private List<Items> _itemLists;
    private MyDbContext _context;

    Constructor()
    {
        _itemLists = _context.Items.ToList();
        _source.Source = _itemLists;
        _source.View.CurrentChanged += View_CurrentChanged;
    }

    private void View_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_source.View.IsCurrentBeforeFirst)
        {
            _source.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
            _source.View.Refresh();
            return;

        }

        if (_source.View.IsCurrentAfterLast)
        {
            _source.View.MoveCurrentToLast();
            _source.View.Refresh();
            return;
        }

        // ... Do some other work here ...
    }
```

I had to put in a return statement in each if blocks to prevent the View.CurrentItem from being NULL.

This works great from preventing a Null exception being thrown, but the strange behavior is that when I try to call `View.MoveCurrentToNext()` after the user tries to go beyond the first record (`IsCurrentViewBeforeFirst`), nothing happens. You have to call it again in order for the View to be updated to the next record after the first one.

Inversely, the same behavior goes for the `IsCurrentViewAfterLast`. You have to call `View.MoveCurrentToPrevious()` twice before the View shows the previous record after the last one when the user tries to go beyond the last record.

So then how can this be fixed so I don't need to call the methods twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent event bubbling in WPF like below:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

I think your CollectionViewSource object inherited from an IEnumerable object. Which has a member as Index you can hide your object in a session or any static container (for example **Application.Current.Resources** in wpf) so you can update just your index while user click next or before buttons.
If your object doesnt inherited from IEnumerable i suggest to this also

Cheer codding

Comment: Nope, there is no e.Handled since EventArgs is being used in the method declaration  which is defined: View_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: is your constructor working every call to your context?